# Do Gaussian Processes not generalize well out of the training range?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, regression, data-analysis

I'm a beginner of the Gaussian Processes (GPs). I would like to know the generalizability of GPs. I trained a GP using training data generated by an objective function (the range $-5<x<5$, 10 sample points).
Now I test the GP using test data generated by the objective with the range $-10<x<10$, 2000 sample points. Here's the picture:[image].
As you can see, the GP well estimates only in the range of training data ($-5<x<5$) and are crap out of the range ($-10<x<-5, 5<x<10$). Is this the nature of GPs? Or I might be wrong with my algorithm...

For your information, I show my algorithm:

```
def objective(x):
  return 2 * np.sin(x) + 3 * np.cos(2 * x) + 5 * np.sin(2 / 3 * x)
  
    
  
x_train=np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
y_train=objective(x_train)


for i in range(len(x_train)):
  y_train[i] += np.random.normal(0, 0.5)




plt.plot(x_train,y_train,"x",label="$y_{train}$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
    
    
def gaussian_kernel(x, x_train, t1=1, t2=0.4):
  xx = (x_train - x) ** 2
  return t1 * np.exp(-xx / t2)

def gpr(x_test, x_train, y_train, kernel, t3=0.1):
    mean = y_train.mean()

    K = []
    for x in x_train:
        K.append(kernel(x, x_train))
    K = np.array(K) + np.eye(len(x_train)) * t3
    A = np.linalg.inv(K)
    yy = np.dot(A, y_train - mean)

    mu = []
    var = [] 
    for x in x_test:
        k = kernel(x, x_train)
        s = gaussian_kernel(x, [x]) + t3
        mu.append(np.dot(k, yy))
        var.append(s[0] - np.dot(k, np.dot(A, k.T)))

    mu = np.array(mu) + mean
    var = np.array(var)

    return mu, var 
        

x_test = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
mu, var = gpr(x_test, x_train, y_train, gaussian_kernel)
plt.plot(x_test, mu)
plt.plot(x_train, y_train, "x", c="C0")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems like you essentially just set the GP to be zero

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "setting to be zero"?

Comment: Look at the blue curve when $|x|>5$

Comment: Note that the horizontal lines on the blue curve show a range on which the function data is constant and these regions characterize the large errors. However you don't need to estimate $0$ since it's constant.

Comment: Why do you expect the GP to do well out of range? What kind of function is your true y?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I see. But I have no idea what cause the setting in my algorithm

Comment: @CyclotomicField But the true function (color orange) never converges to zero, which means I failed to estimate the true function out of the training data

Comment: @AlanChung Because I expect GPs work well to unseen data out of the training data range, just like Deep Neural Networks: In DNNs, If I train a DNN well, the DNN would fit all the curves (orange).

Comment: @SpaceTAKA line 3 of the code says x_train=np.arange(-5, 5, 1). Is that the error?

Comment: @SpaceTAKA that's not really how it works; Deep NNs work well out of sample, but what this means is that the out of sample data come from the same distribution as the input data. You're training on literally new $x$ values that the model has not seen before (like the distribution of the true y is different on these $x$ values as for the input $x$ values) and there's no reason a Deep NN or GP should be able to learn that

Comment: @AlanChung Same distribution, I see. So, if I use the out of sample data come from the same distribution as the input data, the GPs would fit nice?

Comment: @AlanChung I did the training and test from the same dataset but, unfortunately the output worked correctly only in the range of the training data

Comment: @AlanChung Seems like there's a big difference between DNNs and GPs cuz once a DNN completed the training, it works like a function, guessing nice with any input. Meanwhile, GPs works as a fitting machine, meaning works only in the range of training. Right?

Comment: @CyclotomicField The reason why I give x_train=np.arange(-5, 5, 1) as training data is that I want to see how it will generalize well out of the range  (see x_test = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01) )

Comment: @SpaceTAKA that's why you're getting zero outside the range though.

Comment: @CyclotomicField So you are saying GPs are not able to estimate well out of the training range?

Comment: @SpaceTAKA I think this more resembles Gibb's phenomenon. Your data dropping to zero acts like a jump discontinuity. Try an even larger range and see if it starts to fit the data better the further you go.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA I think you are misunderstanding generalization error. DNNs don't "magically predict" new data it hasn't seen before. The point is that if you show a DNN a new data point that is similar to one of the points in the dataset, it does a good job. But this doesn't mean it can fit to completely new things it hasn't seen before.

Comment: @AlanChung I understand what you are saying but my GP literally fails to estimate even if I give test data generated by the same distribution as the training data

Comment: @AlanChung Note that the test data is out of the training range